# Can someone help me identify these berry bushes?

Tags: identification, berries

I moved into a new home in CO in the last 6 months, and just noticed some berry bushes in my front yard.  They seem to be either blueberries, huckleberries, or possibly bilberries.  But I'm hoping someone can help me better identify these berries, and confirm if they are indeed edible.

The berries appear to start our red, and then their color darkens to purple and then to blue as they ripen.  The bushes themselves are about 4-5 ft tall.

Ripe Berries
[image: Ripe Berries]

Ripening Berries
[image: Ripening Berries]

Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is from the family of [serviceberries](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelanchier) which has various names, e.g. "wildplume", but I cannot decide between two species. In any case  they seem to be eatable raw and cooked, but I have not tried it myself.

I am inclined that it may be *[Amelanchier ovalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelanchier_ovalis)*:

> Its pome fruits are edible and can be eaten raw or cooked.

It also may be [Amelanchier canadensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelanchier_canadensis) about what is [said](https://pfaf.org/user/Plant.aspx?LatinName=Amelanchier+canadensis)

> Edible fruit - raw or cooked. The fruit contains a few small seeds at the centre, it has a sweet flavour with a hint of apple. It can be eaten out of hand, used in pies, preserves etc or dried and used like raisins.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely seems like what they are.  The name I'm most familiar for these is "Juneberry"